# Portforwarding Wireguard setup

Tags: port-forwarding, wireguard

I setup wireguard on a VPS to use it as a VPN to enable portforwarding for various uses like gaming and NAS setup.

I want to open port 45000, 56000 and 40000 for now.
I am on Ubuntu 22.4 on 27fiber VPS.

Given below is the UFW rules I have added

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
45000                      ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
45000/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
45000/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
40000:60007/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere
45000 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
45000/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
45000/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
40000:60007/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

10.7.0.2 56000/tcp         ALLOW FWD   Anywhere
10.7.0.2 45000/tcp         ALLOW FWD   Anywhere
10.7.0.2 56000/udp         ALLOW FWD   Anywhere
10.7.0.2 45000/udp         ALLOW FWD   Anywhere
```

**This is my wg0 config**

```
# Do not alter the commented lines
# They are used by wireguard-install
# ENDPOINT 181.xxx.32.x14

[Interface]
Address = 10.7.0.1/24, fddd:xxxxxx::1/64
PrivateKey = xxx
ListenPort = 51xx0

# BEGIN_PEER pcs
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
PresharedKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.7.0.2/32, fddd:xxxx::2/128
# END_PEER pcs
```

This is the /etc/ufw before.rules data

```
#
# rules.before
#
# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
#   ufw-before-input
#   ufw-before-output
#   ufw-before-forward
#

# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
# End required lines


# allow all on loopback
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT

# quickly process packets for which we already have a connection
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# drop INVALID packets (logs these in loglevel medium and higher)
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# ok icmp codes for INPUT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# ok icmp code for FORWARD
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# allow dhcp client to work
-A ufw-before-input -p udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

#
# ufw-not-local
#
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local

# if LOCAL, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN

# if MULTICAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN

# if BROADCAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN

# all other non-local packets are dropped
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP

# allow MULTICAST mDNS for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 224.0.0.251 --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT

# allow MULTICAST UPnP for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 239.255.255.250 --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 56000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2
-A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
-A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 55000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2
-A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

And this is the etc/default ufw file data

```
# /etc/default/ufw
#

# Set to yes to apply rules to support IPv6 (no means only IPv6 on loopback
# accepted). You will need to 'disable' and then 'enable' the firewall for
# the changes to take affect.
IPV6=yes

# Set the default input policy to ACCEPT, DROP, or REJECT. Please note that if
# you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules.
DEFAULT_INPUT_POLICY="ACCEPT"

# Set the default output policy to ACCEPT, DROP, or REJECT. Please note that if
# you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules.
DEFAULT_OUTPUT_POLICY="ACCEPT"

# Set the default forward policy to ACCEPT, DROP or REJECT.  Please note that
# if you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"

# Set the default application policy to ACCEPT, DROP, REJECT or SKIP. Please
# note that setting this to ACCEPT may be a security risk. See 'man ufw' for
# details
DEFAULT_APPLICATION_POLICY="SKIP"

# By default, ufw only touches its own chains. Set this to 'yes' to have ufw
# manage the built-in chains too. Warning: setting this to 'yes' will break
# non-ufw managed firewall rules
MANAGE_BUILTINS=no

#
# IPT backend
#
# only enable if using iptables backend
IPT_SYSCTL=/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf

# Extra connection tracking modules to load. IPT_MODULES should typically be
# empty for new installations and modules added only as needed. See
# 'CONNECTION HELPERS' from 'man ufw-framework' for details. Complete list can
# be found in net/netfilter/Kconfig of your kernel source. Some common modules:
# nf_conntrack_irc, nf_nat_irc: DCC (Direct Client to Client) support
# nf_conntrack_netbios_ns: NetBIOS (samba) client support
# nf_conntrack_pptp, nf_nat_pptp: PPTP over stateful firewall/NAT
# nf_conntrack_ftp, nf_nat_ftp: active FTP support
# nf_conntrack_tftp, nf_nat_tftp: TFTP support (server side)
# nf_conntrack_sane: sane support
IPT_MODULES=""
```

**Issues**
I used this tool https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to check for open ports and the ports are closed.
I tried restarting UFW too no luck.
Please help me with the Config.

Comment: have you enabled packet forwarding?

Comment: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
Yes enabled

Comment: please update the question and add the business related part about the question. please also add more Infos, see here: [ask]

Comment: I don't see any source NATing for packets being forwarded through the wg tunnel, when those packets arrive at your internal server it'll try to reply directly, rather then back through the tunnel. I would add `-A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE` where you have the other NAT rules. You also have `MASQUERADE` on the physical interface twice, that's not necessary, you can delete one of those